Select records from table until a duplicate
Is there a way I can select a set of records from a table ordering by a column till a duplicate.
TableName --> temp
Columns --> key1, key2, key3, key4, rowCount
Select condition

Order by rowcount
Till a duplicate on combination of key1, key2 and key3




key1
key2
key3
key4
rowCount




k1.1
k2.1
k3.1
k4.1
1


k1.2
k2.2
k3.2
k4.2
2


k1.3
k2.3
k3.3
k4.3
3


k1.1
k2.1
k3.1
k4.4
4


k1.5
k2.5
k3.5
k4.5
5


k1.6
k2.6
k3.6
k4.6
6



The select query should return me the following records



key1
key2
key3
key4
rowCount




k1.1
k2.1
k3.1
k4.1
1


k1.2
k2.2
k3.2
k4.2
2


k1.3
k2.3
k3.3
k4.3
3




Please edit your question and add a tag for the specific type of SQL you're using (MySQL, MS-SQL, etc).

Stackoverflow implemented a way of formatting your question, I did correct the formatting, please gt used the the way it is on stackoverflow.com

In table temp only the first record (rowCount=1) is duplicated with the combination of key1, key2 and key3 with rowCount=4. As per your requirement only this first record will be in your result set.  There is something different in result set. It needs to be clarified.

The ranked part assign an incrementing number for each key1, key2, key3 group. To identify dupes we have rn=2.
In firstDupe we find the rowCount value for the first dupe. In the end we select all rows before the dupe.
I have considered that rowCount uniquely identifies every row and has the correct order.
I have used MySQL as template, but it would work on most dbms.

WITH ranked AS (
    SELECT key1, key2, key3, key4, rowCount,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY key1, key2, key3 ORDER BY rowCount ASC) AS rn
    FROM temp
),firstDupe AS (
    SELECT rowCount       
    FROM ranked
    WHERE rn = 2
    ORDER BY rowCount ASC LIMIT 1
)
SELECT r.key1, r.key2, r.key3, r.key4, r.rowCount
FROM ranked r
INNER JOIN firstDupe fd on fd.rowCount > r.rowCount
ORDER BY r.rowCount ASC;

See example

WITH RowNumbered AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY your_column ORDER BY your_sort_column) AS row_num
    FROM
        your_table
)
SELECT *
FROM RowNumbered
WHERE row_num = 1;


The gist of this seems right to me. Downvote is probably because it's just bare code with no explanation.

@Error_2646 Not my downvote, but doesn't cover a lot of nuance for this question: multiple columns in the partition, and the results include rows other than row_num = 1. The selected row only tells them when to stop.

@JoelCoehoorn Right, right. Went cross-eyed. Agreed.
